# A subquery in a select causes my results to not return

Tags: sql, oracle

Hello I have an issue with a very convoluted query, I did not write the query but I have to maintain it.

I have the below super long query which was working fine for a while(slow but fine) but some time in the last month it stopped working.  we don't get an error it just times out returning results.

Now, if I run this fun query below with the first sub query within the selection criteria removed the results return the top 50 in 136 seconds.

If I leave it in it just times out after a few hours.  Also to note if I take the sub query in the select statement and run it on it's own hard coding any values passed in to it returns the result in 0.004 seconds.

If I leave it all in but go to the very core query in this long query and put a restriction on the SDDOCO so it will return a single result I get the result in 94 seconds and it doesn't matter if I have the sub query in the select or not.

I think that one of the results is causing issues and bogging down the query but I can't think of a good way to figure out which item would cause this.. my result set when it returns is 47k records.

Any suggestions on where I can look or how I can investigate this further would be greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT
SUM((GL.GLAA/100) * (CAST(COALESCE((Select CXCRR from PRODDTA.F0015 F2 WHERE CXEFT = (SELECT MAX(CXEFT) FROM PRODDTA.F0015 F3 WHERE F3.CXEFT <= GL.GLDGJ) and CXCRCD = GL.GLCRCD AND CXCRDC ='USD'), 1) AS NUMERIC(15,4)))) TEST1,
SUM((GL.GLAA/100)) test2
FROM (SELECT MAX(SDAN8) SDAN8, MAX(SDMCU) SDMCU, MAX(SDDOCO) SDDOCO, MAX(SDDOC) SDDOC, MAX(SDSHAN) SDSHAN, CASE WHEN NVL(TRIM(TMURRF),' ') = ' ' then SDURRF ELSE TMURRF END SDURRF, MAX(SDDCTO) SDDCTO, MAX(SDDGL) SDDGL, MAX(SDASN) SDASN
    , SUM(CASE WHEN IMGLPT like 'FG%' THEN (CASE WHEN NOT (UMCONV IS NULL) THEN SDSOQS/100 * UMCONV/10000000 else SDSOQS/100 END) ELSE 0 END) AS SDSOQS
    , SUM(CASE WHEN IMGLPT = 'FG04' THEN (CASE WHEN NOT (UMCONV IS NULL) THEN SDSOQS/100 * UMCONV/10000000 ELSE SDSOQS/100 END) ELSE 0 END) AS AER_SDSOQS
    , SUM(CASE WHEN IMGLPT like 'FG%' THEN (CASE WHEN SDSRP5 = '527' THEN (CASE WHEN NOT (UMCONV IS NULL) THEN SDSOQS/100 * UMCONV/10000000 ELSE SDSOQS/100 END) ELSE 0 END) ELSe 0 END) AS MDJ_SDSOQS
    , MAX(SDIVD) SDIVD, MAX(SDADDJ) SDADDJ
    , SUM(CASE WHEN SDWTUM = 'LB' THEN SDITWT WHEN UCCONV is not null then SDITWT*(UCCONV/10000000) WHEN CONV is not null THEN SDSOQS*CONV*10 ELSE 0 END)/10000 AS WEIGHT
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN IMGLPT like 'FG%' THEN 
      CASE 
            WHEN SDWTUM = 'LB' THEN  SDITWT 
            WHEN UCCONV IS NOT NULL THEN SDITWT*(UCCONV/10000000)
            WHEN CONV is not null THEN SDSOQS*CONV*10
            ELSE 0 END
    ELSE 0
    end)/10000 as FG_WEIGHT,
    SUM(CASE WHEN IMGLPT = 'FG04' THEN 
      CASE 
            WHEN SDWTUM = 'LB' THEN  SDITWT 
            WHEN UCCONV IS NOT NULL THEN SDITWT*(UCCONV/10000000)
            WHEN CONV is not null THEN SDSOQS*CONV*10
            ELSE 0 END
    ELSE 0
    end)/10000 as AER_WEIGHT,
    SUM(CASE WHEN SDSRP5 = '527' THEN 
      CASE 
            WHEN SDWTUM = 'LB' THEN  SDITWT 
            WHEN UCCONV IS NOT NULL THEN SDITWT*(UCCONV/10000000)
            WHEN CONV is not null THEN SDSOQS*CONV*10
            ELSE 0 END
    ELSE 0
    end)/10000 as MDJ_WEIGHT,
    SUM(CASE WHEN IMGLPT = 'FG07' THEN 
      CASE 
            WHEN SDWTUM = 'LB' THEN  SDITWT 
            WHEN UCCONV IS NOT NULL THEN SDITWT*(UCCONV/10000000)
            WHEN CONV is not null THEN SDSOQS*CONV*10
            ELSE 0 END
    ELSE 0
    end)/10000 as MDJ_3rdParty_WEIGHT, max(SDCARS) SDCARS
  FROM PRODDTA.F42119
  left join proddta.F554202x on trim(SDURRF) = trim(TMUSRRSV1) and SDDOCO = TMDOCO
  LEFT JOIN PRODDTA.F4101 ON IMITM = SDITM
  LEFT JOIN PRODDTA.F41002 ON UMITM = SDITM AND SDMCU = UMMCU AND SDUOM = UMUM AND UMRUM = imuom1
  left join PRODDTA.F41003 on UCUM = SDWTUM and UCRUM = 'LB'
  Left JOin (SELECT UMMCU as MCU, UMITM as ITM, UMUM as UM, max(CASE WHEN UMRUM = 'LB' THEN UMCONV/10000000 ELSE UMCONV/10000000 * UCCONV/10000000 END) AS CONV 
    FROM PRODDTA.F41002
    LEFT JOIN PRODDTA.F41003
      ON UMRUM = UCUM
    WHERE (UCRUM = 'LB' OR UMRUM = 'LB')
    GROUP BY UMMCU, UMITM, UMUM) CONV2
  ON MCU = SDMCU AND ITM = SDITM AND UM = SDUOM
    WHERE SDLNTY = 'S' 
    AND SDSOQS > 0 
    and not ((SDLTTR = 980 AND SDNXTR = 999) OR SDSOCN = SDUORG) 
    and SDSRP1 <> 'BLK' 
    and not exists (select SDDOCO from proddta.F42119 GA where SDADDJ >= FISCALPERIODSTART(14,1) and SDADDJ <= FISCALPERIODEND(14,12) and SDUOM = 'GA' and F42119.SDDOCO = GA.SDDOCO)
    and SDDOCO in (1230256,1227461,1230628,1225291,1225297,1231601,1242703,1248671,1249556,1244905)
  GROUP BY CASE WHEN NVL(TRIM(TMURRF),' ') = ' ' then SDURRF ELSE TMURRF END) DTL
Left JOIN PRODDTA.F0101 BT ON BT.ABAN8 = DTL.SDAN8
Left JOIN PRODDTA.F0101 ST ON ST.ABAN8 = DTL.SDSHAN
INNER JOIN PRODDTA.F0911 GL
ON TRIM(GL.GLEXR) = TRIM(DTL.SDURRF)
WHERE GLDCT = 'PV' AND GLDGJ >= KIKDATETOJUL(KIKE1JULTODATE(FISCALPERIODSTART(14,1)) - 90) and GLDGJ <= KIKDATETOJUL(KIKE1JULTODATE(FISCALPERIODEND(14,12)) + 90) AND GLOBJ IN ('5025','5026') AND  GLLT ='AA' AND GLEXTL <> 'AM' AND GLEXR <> ' ' and GLRE = ' '
GROUP BY GL.GLEXR, GL.GLDCT, 
CASE WHEN SDDCTO IN ('ST','SJ') THEN CAST(SDSHAN AS NCHAR(12)) ELSE TRIM(SDMCU) END, DTL.SDASN, DTL.SDDOC, DTL.SDDOCO, DTL.SDDCTO, DTL.SDSOQS, DTL.AER_SDSOQS, DTL.MDJ_SDSOQS, DTL.SDSHAN, DTL.SDAN8, SDURRF, GL.GLSUB, Weight, FG_Weight, AER_WEIGHT, MDJ_WEIGHT, MDJ_3rdParty_WEIGHT
```

Comment: Probably the execution plan Oracle uses has changed. Given the speed of the subquery returning on its own, possibly hinting can improve the performance of the query. Can you add the execution plan to your question?

Comment: I don't have permission to post a picture yet, and the copy of the table dump is not formatting correctly is there a different way to post the info?

Comment: @Stephen try pasting the table, select all and hit Ctrl+k. If it's not working, paste it anyway & ping me, I'll try to correct the formatting

Comment: @Sathya I have put the data dump in the original post.

Comment: @StephenArchbold ok that's not readable.. maybe take a screenshot of the explain plan in Toad/ Oracle SQL developer & upload the image?

Comment: @Sathya I don't have enough rank here to post a screen.

Comment: But We where provided with some code to add to the start of the SQL by an ORCAL DBA we happened to have consulting for us for a different project which has the query running lighting fast now.

Comment: @StephenArchbold You can upload and image to imgur.com & edit the link to the question. Also, you should post an answer with what the DBA suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We where provided with the below code to run ahead of the select statement which changes the way the Oracle DB optimizes the query.

```
alter session set optimizer_index_caching=0;
alter session set optimizer_index_cost_adj=80;
```

This fixed the issue.